# Jinja2/Flask: sort-error when list contains None's

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, nonetype

I use Flask/Jinja2 to render a simple model to a table. Everything works just fine, but if i try to sort and attribute which can be None, I get a

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
```

I implement the `__lt__`, `__gt__` methods to be able to sort my objects.

My first class is a Task-class. It has an foreign key to the Person-class. I wanna sort by the Person-class, but None is a legitimate state of person.

template snippet

```
 {% for t in tasks | sort(attribute=sort_on) %}
```

models.py snippet:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable=False,unique=True)
    tasks = db.relationship('Task', backref='resource', lazy='dynamic')

    def __lt__(self,other):
        if other == None:
            return True
        return self.name.__lt__(other.name)

    def __gt__(self,other):
        if other == None:
            return False
        return self.name.__gt__(other.name)


class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300),nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text)
    prio = db.Column(db.Integer)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'),nullable=False)
    planned_days = db.Column(db.Integer)
    done = db.Column(db.Integer)
    state_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('state.id'),nullable=False)
    issue = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this??

Comment: When comparing things to `None` you should check identity, not equality. `if other is None:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At issue here is that you have *multiple* `None` values in your list to sort on, and `None` objects are not by themselves sortable:

```
>>> sorted([None, None])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
```

The trick then is to supply a tiebreaker:

```
>>> sorted([(None, 1), (None, 0)])
[(None, 0), (None, 1)]
```

Here the list contains tuples being sorted; when the first element of a tuple is equal the tie is broken on the basis of the next element.

In Jinja2 you cannot easily do this directly, as the built-in [`sort` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#sort) doesn't let you sort by arbitrary key function.

Ideally, you should really do this in SQL code, not in a template or Python code:

```
if sort_on == 'person':
    query = Task.query.join(Task.person_id).order_by(Person.name)
```

but in Python code you could extract the tuple (with the tiebreaker being a `Task` attribute):

```
sorted(tasks, key=lambda t: (t.person and t.person.name, task.name))
```